# What is the best way to install full extension drawer slides in a cabinet?

Tags: technique, furniture

I have built a large cabinet with some two columns of drawers. I am using 28" full-extension, 100 pound, side mount drawer slides. I want both columns to have the same spacing on the drawers. The cabinet does not have a face frame.

[Kreg](https://www.kregtool.com/customer-service/contact-us.aspx) used to sell a jig for this purpose, but it has been discontinued.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link or picture for the jig anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a spacer which is basically just a piece of scrap wood cut to width to make sure they are all the same. And with no face frame I would just add false fronts to the drawers to cover the slides and is also easier then to ensure your gap around them is even. I think I learned of this trick in Fine Woodworking's website, if I find it I will post a link.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar site using the same concept.

http://www.woodworkingtips.com/etips/2009/03/26/sn/

Comment: That is an awesome way of doing business for installing the drawer slides. With that said, you should include the text of the article in your answer, making sure to include referencing back to the original article (the URL will do). That way if the link ever goes stale, the information will still be here. Good find, nonetheless!

Comment: This is what I do.  I was looking to see if anyone had any better ideas.  I usually have variable spacing on my drawers so I make a different shim out of 3/8" MDF for each spacing.  If I am using face frames, I use the same process for placing the boards that I mount the slides to.

Answer (score 9):

If you can't buy the jig; make it!

Take a scrap of wood cut it to length and add a hook, then rip it in half.

This means that you can clamp it on the drawer to serve as a spacer for one end of the slides and between the slides on the cabinet side.

[image]
(image from [woodgears.ca](http://woodgears.ca/dresser/finish_up.html))

The reason for ripping the scrap in half is to get 2 blocks with for all intents and purposes the same geometry without needing to be very precise twice.

Comment: I was just about to say you can make the jig yourself, but this is better :) Not all jigs have to be as incredible as Mattias Wendal's (jeebas that guy makes neat jigs), but simple ones aren't usually too hard. I often make one-shot jigs that go in the scrap heap when a project is finished because they can be made specific to the task at hand, and keeping every jig I make would just take up too much room.

Comment: I was looking specifically for mounting the slides onto the carcass, not on the drawers.  I normally rip a piece of wood and measure up from the bottom rather than down from the top, but I will definitely keep this idea in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Rockler had such a jig in their catalog,  last I checked. Presumably competing woodworking supply stores have something similar.